# Google Maps V3 Keyboard Accessibility

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm building a map which i would like to be keyboard accessible. V3 is by default keyboard accessible but it seems you cannot access the keyboard functionality until the map has been clicked on. I added a link to select which brings you to the div tag which contains the map but this has not worked. Is there some way to activate the general map click event without actually using the mouse.

Thank you,

g

Comment: See approach here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13060527/1417588

Answer (score 5):

The way I usually do this is to start by making the map div focussable by adding `tabindex="0"` to it. That adds it into the browser's natural tab order. Then I add an event listener for `keyup` with a switch that calls map.panBy or map.setZoom depending on the key pressed. Here's a jQuery example, but the same can be done with `google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'keyup', function() {...etc.});`. jQuery makes the event.which cross-browser for you, so the code is simpler.

```
$('#map').keyup(function(event) {
    var o = 128; // half a tile's width 
    switch(event.which) {
        case 37: // leftArrow
            map.panBy(-o,0);
            break;
        case 38: // upArrow
            map.panBy(0,-o);
            break;
        case 39: // rightArrow
            map.panBy(o,0);
            break;
        case 40: // downArrow
            map.panBy(0,o);
            break;
        case 109: // numpad -
        case 189: // -
            map.setZoom(map.getZoom()-1);
            break;
        case 107: // numpad +
        case 187: // =
            map.setZoom(map.getZoom()+1);
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what this code does. I basically want to make my site to have a link to select which activates a click event on the map, or enable the user to tab down to the map, press enter and thus select the map.

Comment: With this code, you don't need the extra link. This lets the user tab down to the map, and press up/down/left/right/+/- to pan/zoom. A keyboard user shouldn't have to find a link to make the map keyboard accessible. Also, they shouldn't have to press enter to give something focus when it already has focus.

Comment: I tried your code and it worked! The only thing that seems to be a problem now is accessing the map markers/clusters with the keyboard. If i click on a marker an infowindow displays but right now there is no way to select a marker with the keyboard. I was just curious if this is possible.

Comment: I don't think that's possible because of the way google maps v3 renders markers. They're no longer simple divs with png backgrounds. They're drawn onto the tiles beneath them either via canvas or some alternative for older IEs. And since google maps insists on not assigning ids or special classes to markers, you have no way to access them. At least in v2, you could drill down through the DOM tree to get at the markers. In v3 you get as far as a canvas element, and then you're stuck.

Comment: If you're using the standard marker clusterer, then you can drill down the DOM to get at the divs (look for divs with a style attribute containing m1.png, m2.png, m3.png, m4.png, or m5.png).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [`focus()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.focus) function?

Comment: I tried using the focus function. I created a button with an onclick event which references a function i created called getfocus(). The function looked like this:                         function getfocus() { document.getElementById("map").focus(); }    I was hoping that this would do the trick but it did not. There is no way to tab down to the map and select it either.