# activate Google maps keyboard bindings immediately after page load

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

is it possible to activate the keyboard bindings of Google Maps (StreetView) immediately after page load? I found a working example [here](http://devfiles.myopera.com/articles/523/demo04.html), unfortunately it uses the Google Maps API v2 which is no longer supported. If you embed a normal Google Maps StreetView, keyboard bindings works not before you click on the map initially (see [here](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-map)).

Is there a possibility to do this in v3? I already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10334380/arrow-keys-navigation-on-google-maps-without-clicking-the-map) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195814/google-maps-v3-keyboard-accessibility/9218055#9218055) without success because thats not working for streetview.

**Update:** with keyboard bindings I have especially the arrow keys in mind to move around the map

Thanks

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found a solution and created a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/christian-bromann/5392762) for that.

Answer (score 0):

The solution proposed by @ChristianB did not work for me. Maybe because it works for an older version of the Google Maps API (mine is v3), or it uses a different rendering mode (mine is webgl, which uses a canvas).

What I did is wait for the position_changed event to trigger, then set a tabIndex attribute on the canvas element, and then trigger the focus() on the canvas element. After that the keyboard bindings work.

The code:

```
var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama({
  ...
  //forcing webgl 
  mode: 'webgl'
});

//Set an event listener for position_changed, 
//this will be triggered the first time the panorama is loaded, 
//and every time the position changes
google.maps.event.addListener(panorama, 'position_changed', function() {
  //This is how to get the canvas in my current version of the Google Maps API, 
  //note that this might change in the future.
  var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas.widget-scene-canvas');

  //first set a tabindex on the canvas, 
  //without it focus will not make the canvas the active element
  canvas.setAttribute("tabindex", "-1");
  canvas.focus();

  //To test that it worked you can check that document.activeElement is the canvas
  console.log(document.activeElement);
});
```

You might want to put the code in a separate function and call it any time the canvas loses focus.

Code tested in Google Chrome v55.

Comment: yeah my solution definitely targets an old GMaps API